# Conditional operator mis-matching

Tags: python, c++, conditional-statements

When I execute in python following code

```
print(0<5<2)
```

It gives False as output
but same thing in C++

```
std::cout<<(0<5<2);
```

returns True

Why this contradiction?

Comment: Python and C++ have massive differences. There might be some rule in Python to evaluate such expressions.

Comment: I know that cpp evaluates from left to right so for it the expression is True. But how python evaluates 2 conditionals?

Comment: In c++ `std::cout << (0<5<2)` is similar to `bool tmp = 0<5; std::cout << (tmp < 2)` . So, is your question about why C++ behaves this way, or why Python behaves the way it does. short answers: In both cases its because *that's how that language works*.

Comment: In Python, `a < b < c` is equivalent to `a < b and b < c`.

Comment: Python implements comparison chaining, similar to standard mathematical notation. `0 < 5 < 2` is a single expression equivalent to `0 < 5 and 5 < 2`, not a nested expression parsed like either `(0<5)<2` or `0<(5<2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, `0 < 5 < 2` is equivalent to `0 < 5 and 5 < 2`.
In C++, it is equivalent to `static_cast<int>(0 < 5) < 2`.

The Python shorthand is originally inspired by mathematics, but has been so generalized that you can write really strange stuff, like

```
>>> 1 < 5 in [2,3,4]
False
>>> 1 < 5 in [2,3,5]
True
```

and confuse all your friends.

Comment: `1 < 5 in [2,3,5]` is `1 < 5 and 5 in [2,3,5]`.

Answer (score 3):

Because they are different language that has different syntax and work differently.

In the case of `c++`, the statement is evaluated from left to right.

```
0<5 == true

true < 2, this will trigger an implicit conversion from true to 1

1 < 2 == true, which is the end result
```

Python has different rules for how the language works.
I don't know them, but clearly they lead to different result in this case.